# Set interval change?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){
        $('#fetchstatuses').load('statuses/statuses.php')
    }, 1000);

});

<div id="fetchstatuses"></div>
```

I use this for loading statuses on page inside mentioned div above. But when I add comment form to statuses as:

for each status i echo status and on the bottom the code for comment with form with textarea and submit button....

My problem is that interval loads everything and i can't comment cuz textarea get reloaded in sec every time. When I remove interval from code, the whole script, my statuses got loading to long and images for like buttons load too long. Also when I try to stop the script till my comment form is opened and start after the comment it won't work. So does anyone know different way for this or something that can be used in this method??

Comment: Why not just remove the textarea from the content that gets loaded and have it permanently in the page?

Comment: Because all statuses are inside that file not one...

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand the problem, but if it is about starting/stopping/pausing a timer/interval, than you have one Option for both `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`.

Both methods return the ID of the time-out or interval, which can be used to cancel each of them.

```
//1. getting the IDs
var timeOutID  = setTimeout(function () { … }, 1000),
    intervalID = setInterval(function () { … }, 1000);

//2. clearing the time-out/interval
clearTimeout(timeOutID);
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Restarting is essentially step 1, but remind that the returned IDs are unique each time.

I hope I could help.

Comment: It can be about pausing interval, i just need to pause loading for time i am typing the comment and after I click comment button to continue interval... Is starting same as continuing or not?

Comment: Or should I just include file inside fetch div and inside that file use setInterval and load just before comment form? Or load just how many people liked or is status edited...? I was working all night in bakery so I don't think well now...

Comment: In fact, your code above creates a new request each 1000ms, once this one is finished the complete content of `#fetchstatuses` will be replaced. So the overall time to replace is `1000ms + timeNeededForTheRequest`, what actually can differ very strong, so that the order wont be preserved. Additionally I do not really understand what are trying.

Comment: I have a qquestion can i set interval to load div only or should I make that div in one file and then set interval because i need it for loadin comments and likes.. not whole status... i tried but it start ruining my whole page and loading whole page not just that one div ...

Comment: To answer that question you need to provide more code. I do not understand what you mean with: "can i set interval to load div only", or "make that div in one file". If you want to poll Data from the server and append that in you HTML, than you should start to look out to learn AJAX and you will see that there are a lot of different approaches to solve problems like yours. Time-outs or Intervals are just the peak of the iceberg, as well as the question if a `<div>` should reside in a file.